# Get a set of date/time ranges based on DB data

Tags: sql

I've got a SQL 2005 DB full of activity records that include a DateTime column, a DeviceID, and various bits of data. I need a query that will give me a list of date/time ranges based on DeviceID (possibly limited by a start/end time). Also, I would consider a new range as starting at least 60min after the old one ended (if it's less than 60min, then it's part of the old range).

Example data:

```
DateTime                 DeviceID
2009-10-11 12:01:30      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:02:30      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:03:21      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:04:30      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:05:45      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:06:10      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:07:40      Dev1
2009-10-11 12:08:20      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:30:11      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:32:21      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:36:45      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:39:16      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:42:18      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:46:22      Dev1
2009-10-11 13:48:35      Dev1
```

Expected Results:

```
StartDate                EndDate
2009-10-11 12:01:30      2009-10-11 12:08:20
2009-10-11 13:30:11      2009-10-11 13:48:35
```

Answer (score 0):

Read something about [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Then look at this query:

```
SELECT <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  DeviceID,<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  "DateTime",<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeviceID ORDER BY "DateTime") OrdinalNumber<br>
FROM TableName

Then look at this query:

WITH DateTable <br>
AS<br>
(SELECT <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  DeviceID,<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp; "DateTime",<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeviceID ORDER BY "DateTime") OrdinalNumber<br>
FROM TableName)<br>
SELECT <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  D1.DeviceID,<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  D1."DateTime" EndDate,<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  D2."DateTime" StartDate<br>
FROM DateTable D1<br>
JOIN DateTable D2<br>
ON (D1.DeviceID = D2.DeviceID) <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  AND (D1.OrdinalNumber = D2.OrdinalNumber - 1) <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;  AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,D1."DateTime",D2."DateTime") >= 60)<br>
```

We are looking for gaps with more than 60 minute difference.

Now You have to take `StartDate` from every row and match it with `EndDate` from next. Since it is 4AM, I'll leave it to You:)